# Redirect whole website to one url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have multiple views in my website, some code:

```
  $this->load->view('templates/header');
  $this->load->view('main');
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

I have an div in the main where I load another view when you click on a button.
The js code:

```
$("#side").load("/admin/side/loadNewContact", function(e) {
      $("#side").removeClass('hide');
});
```

A separate function checks if the user is stil valid and logged in everytime A request is done.

When the user is not valid the system needs to go to the login page.
I have this code for it:

```
redirect('/', 'location');
```

This works. But now the problem.

When I load an page inside the main with the js, and a user is not valid. The system redirects to / (the login page). But the view what you get is loaded in the side, that is not what I want. I want that the whole system is redirected to the login instead of that specific view.

Comment: Can't you make it with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand problem corectly, you would need if than else that wraps current jQuery code:

```
//pseudo code
var valid_user = <?php echo $valid_user;//this should be value or FALSE/NULL?>

if (valid_user) {
    $("#side").load("/admin/side/loadNewContact", function(e) {
        $("#side").removeClass('hide');
    });
} else {
    // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
    //window.location.replace("<?php echo base_url();?>");

    // similar behavior as clicking on a link
    //window.location.href = "/";
}
```

You want to check JavaScript variable at the beginning of the file/document so you can make similar conditions due the file accordingly. I am saying that in case of buttons/classes need to be shown regarding `valid_user` state.